# How to define an common iterator to my class hirerachy

Tags: c++, iterator

My team designed a library meant to store data from different "signals". A signal is a list of timestamped float values. We have three way to store a signal (depending of the way it was recorded from the hardware in the first place):

- `MarkerSignal`: We store a sorted `std::vector` of `std::pair` of `(boost::posix_time::ptime,float)`
- `RawSignal`: We store a start time (`boost::posix_time::ptime`), a sampling period (`boost::posix_time::time_duration`) and finally a `std::vector` of `float` (each value's timestamp is `start time + period * value's index in the vector`)
- `NumericalSignal`: We store a start time (`boost::posix_time::ptime`), a sampling period (`boost::posix_time::time_duration`), a scale (`float`), an offset (`float`) and finally a `std::vector` of `short` (timestamp is computed as for `RawSignal` and `float` value is `short*scale+offset`)

Those three signals have a common parent class (`SignalBase`) storing the signal's name, description, unit and stuff like that. We use the visitor pattern to let people nicely "cast" the `SignalBase` to a `MarkerSignal`/`RawSignal`/`NumericalSignal` and then access the data it contains.

In the end, what we need for each class is to iterate through all elements, one element being actually a pair of `(boost::posix_time::ptime,float)` (like `MarkerSignal`). And it's a pain having to create a visitor every time we want to do that.

Storing all signals as a `std::vector<std::pair<boost::posix_time::ptime,float>>` (or returning an object of this kind on demand) uses too much memory.

We thought the best was probably to define our own iterator object. The iterator would give access to the timestamp and value, like that:

```
SignalBase* signal = <any signal>;
for ( SignalBase::iterator iter = signal->begin();
      iter != signal->end();
      ++iter )
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime timestamp = iter.time();
    float value = iter.value();
}
```

**What's the best approach/strategy to create such an iterator class?** (simple class with a `size_t` index attribute, or a `MarkerSignal`/`RawSignal`/`NumericalSignal` container's specific iterator as attribute, store a `std::pair<boost::posix_time::ptime,float>` and update it from a `++` operator...).

Also, I would much prefer if the solution rpoposed avoids using a virtual table (to have `++`, `time()`, and `value()` be faster when iterating on huge signals).

Comment: What is the rationale of avoiding late binding when you use visitor pattern?

Comment: We propose visitor interface because some operations must be specifically done on the child classes (like MarkerSignal provides a function to insert a new value, other classes does not).

Comment: Using abstraction always enforce additional cost of virtual table map lookup. To avoid late binding you could use static polymorphism but it is only the matter of design (in my opinion the visitor pattern does not fit your needs)...

Comment: But with or without having a visitor, what would be the best strategy to declare an iterator class for SignalBase objects?

Comment: Having SignalBase indirectly implies using abstraction... If you really value for efficiency by avoiding virtual table in your design you probably have to downcast to appropriate child signal and retrieve specific for the signal class iterator... To avoid code duplication you may find useful templates parameterized with specific signal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wanted something easy to use for people using my library (be able to esily do a for loop) I finally implemented my own iterator like that:

Added two virtual functions in `SignalBase` (found no alternative to that, runtime will use the virtual table):

```
virtual size_t floatDataCount() const = 0;
virtual bool loadFloatInfoAt( size_t pos, SignalFloatIter::ValueInfo& info ) const = 0;
```

Added functions in `SignalBase` to get begin/end iterators:

```
inline BDL::SignalFloatIter beginFloatIter() const { return BDL::SignalFloatIter::beginIter( *this ); }
inline BDL::SignalFloatIter endFloatIter() const { return BDL::SignalFloatIter::endIter( *this ); }
```

Declared iterator class like that:

```
class SignalFloatIter
{
public:
    SignalFloatIter( const SignalBase* signal = NULL, size_t pos = 0 );
    SignalFloatIter( const SignalFloatIter& iter );

    static SignalFloatIter beginIter( const SignalBase& signal );
    static SignalFloatIter endIter( const SignalBase& signal );

    SignalFloatIter& operator=( const SignalFloatIter& iter );

    bool operator==( const SignalFloatIter& iter ) const;
    bool operator!=( const SignalFloatIter& iter ) const;

    /** Pre-increment operator */
    SignalFloatIter& operator++();

    /** Post-increment operator */
    SignalFloatIter operator++(int unused);

    inline const BDL::time& when() const { assert( m_valid ); return m_info.first.first; }
    inline const BDL::duration& duration() const { assert( m_valid ); return m_info.first.second; }
    inline const float& value() const { assert( m_valid ); return m_info.second; }
    inline size_t index() const { assert( m_valid ); return m_pos; }
    inline BDL::MarkerKey markerKey() const { assert( m_valid ); return std::make_pair( when(), duration() ); }
    inline bool valid() const { return m_valid; }

    typedef std::pair<BDL::time,BDL::duration> TimeInfo;
    typedef std::pair<TimeInfo,float> ValueInfo;

private:
    const SignalBase* m_signal;
    size_t m_pos;
    bool m_valid;
    ValueInfo m_info;

    void loadCurInfo();
};
```

Implemented:

```
SignalFloatIter::SignalFloatIter( const SignalBase* signal, size_t pos ) :
    m_signal( signal ),
    m_pos( pos )
{
    loadCurInfo();
}

SignalFloatIter::SignalFloatIter( const SignalFloatIter& iter )
{
    operator=( iter );
}

SignalFloatIter SignalFloatIter::beginIter( const SignalBase& signal )
{
    return SignalFloatIter( &signal, 0 );
}

SignalFloatIter SignalFloatIter::endIter( const SignalBase& signal )
{
    return SignalFloatIter( &signal, signal.floatDataCount() );
}

SignalFloatIter& SignalFloatIter::operator=( const SignalFloatIter& iter )
{
    if ( this != &iter )
    {
        m_signal = iter.m_signal;
        m_pos = iter.m_pos;
        m_info = iter.m_info;
        m_valid = iter.m_valid;
    }
    return *this;
}

bool SignalFloatIter::operator==( const SignalFloatIter& iter ) const
{
    if ( m_signal == iter.m_signal )
    {
        if ( m_pos == iter.m_pos )
        {
            assert( m_valid == iter.m_valid );
            if ( m_valid )
                assert( m_info == iter.m_info );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false );
        return false;
    }
}

bool SignalFloatIter::operator!=( const SignalFloatIter& iter ) const
{
    return !( *this == iter );
}

SignalFloatIter& SignalFloatIter::operator++()
{
    ++m_pos;
    loadCurInfo();
    return *this;
}

SignalFloatIter SignalFloatIter::operator++( int unused )
{
    SignalFloatIter old = *this;
    assert( unused == 0 ); // see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec
    ++m_pos;
    loadCurInfo();
    return old;
}

void SignalFloatIter::loadCurInfo()
{ 
    if ( m_signal )
    {
        m_valid = m_signal->loadFloatInfoAt( m_pos, m_info );
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false );
        m_valid = false;
    }
}
```

It's pretty straightforward and easy to use for any signal:

```
std::cout << "Signal timestamped data are: ";
for ( BDL::SignalFloatIter iter = signal.beginFloatIter();
      iter != signal.endFloatIter();
      ++iter )
{
    std::cout << iter.when() << " : " << iter.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up I think the best you can achieve if you value for efficiency could be something like this:

```
template <typename SignalType, typename Functor = function<void(typename SignalType::value_type&&) > >
void iterateThroughSignal(SignalBase *signal, Functor foo) {
    SignalType *specificSignal = dynamic_cast<SignalType *>(signal);
    if (!specificSignal)
        return;
    for (typename SignalType::iterator it = specificSignal->begin();
         it != specificSignal->end();
         it++) {
       foo(*it); // retrieving value from iterator...
    }
}
```

Then for call:

```
iterateThroughSignal<MarkerSignal>(signal, [](MarkerSignal::value_type&& msv){ 
   /*doing something with value...*/ 
});
```

I'm not sure if you are using C++11 so the lambda can be replace by function pointer, rvalue reference using lvalue reference and the std::function with a function signature...

**Edit:**
To make it compile when the type of the `foo` signature won't match the `SignalType::value_type` there will be a need of playing a little bit with sfinae:

```
template <typename SignalType> 
class IterateHelper {
    template <typename Functor>
    static typename enable_if<first_param_is<Functor, typename SignalType::value_type>::value >::type iterateThroughSignal(SignalBase *signal, Functor foo) {
        SignalType *specificSignal = dynamic_cast<SignalType *>(signal);
        if (!specificSignal)
            return;
        for (typename SignalType::iterator it = specificSignal->begin();
            it != specificSignal->end();
            it++) {
            foo(*it); // retrieving value from iterator...
       }
    }
    template <typename Functor>
    static typename enable_if<!first_param_is<Functor, typename SignalType::value_type>::value >::type iterateThroughSignal(SignalBase *signal, Functor foo) {
    }
};
```

I leave the implementation of first_param_is helper struct to you... Call would change to:

```
IteratorHelper<MarkerSignal>::iterateThroughSignal(signal, [](MarkerSignal::value_type&& msv){ 
   /*doing something with value...*/ 
});
```